# Azure service bus healthcheck status always returning unhealthy

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azureservicebus, health-check

I am trying to implement a health check in one of my application which is .Netcore service by refering to [Readme.md](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks) file.

Here is my code in startup.cs file

```
services.AddHealthChecks()
                .AddAzureServiceBusQueue(connectionString: Configuration["ServiceBusSettings:ConnectionString"],
                    queueName: Configuration["ServiceBusSettings:QueueName"], tags: new[] { "readiness" })
                .AddCheck("Ping", () => HealthCheckResult.Healthy(), tags: new[] { "liveness" })
                .AddUrlGroup(new Uri($"{Configuration["ReservationApi:Url"]}/healthcheck"), name: "ReservationApi Api Healthcheck", tags: new[] { "readiness" });
```

Both AddCheck, AddUrlGroup are showing healthy. The problem is I am able to push messages successfully to the queue but in the health check, it is showing unhealthy for ASB queue status.

Reference screenshot
[image]

Please help me to resolve this issue where I am doing wrong or pls suggest me is  there a better to know azure service bus health status

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you confirm if you are using the Manage access keys for authenticating the service bus resource as I can see someone reporting that it needs manager access : https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/issues/727

Hope this helps you to resolve the issue.

Comment: thanks, @MayankBargali-MSFT, I just came to know that they are some restrictions in using this library in my company VPN network for knowing the health status of azure resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others, if someone else is facing the issue. Then please verify the below actions

- Verify whether you are using the Manage access keys for authenticating the service bus resource.
- Test your code in a different network to verify if there an issue with the network/restriction.
- You can use any of the debugging tools to capture the traffic to verify whether there are any requests initiate from your client machine and what was the response.